# Zend Framework 2 Namespace ambiguity

Tags: php, namespaces, zend-framework2, autoload

I am writing an API for Jambase by using Zend/Http from Zend Framework 2 . Here is my folder structure.

```
Jambase
|---composer.json
|---composer.phar
|---src
|----Jambase
|------|Service
|---------|Jambase.php
|---vendor
|-----|bin
|-----|composer
|-----|zendframework
|--------|zendframework
|-----------|library
|--------------|Zend
|----------------|Http
|--------------
|----vendor
```

So basically my api sdk class is in Jambase.php under service folder. in that i had header like this, 
namespace Jambase\Service;

```
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface,
    Zend\Authentication\Result,
    Zend\Http\Client,
    Zend\Json\Json;
```

When the run the application i get an error saying,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Http\Client' not found in /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/jambaseclient-php/src/Jambase/Service/Jambase.php
```

I know this is a namespace or autoload issue, can someone help ? 
It works with absolute paths. Not the relative paths.

Comment: What is the namespace of your `Module.php` file ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a structure which is loadable via composer, as I see a `composer.json` file in your project. There is indeed an autoloading issue and you can resolve this via composer.

The point is, php must know you have the `Zend\Http\Client` class available, but you must tell php it's available under `/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/jambaseclient-php/vendor/zendframework/zendframework\library\Zend\Http\Client.php`.

In the `vendor` directory there is a file called `autoload.php`. In your application, when you start it, you **must** load this file. Then you can load all Zend Framework 2 code like you do now.

In order to help you further, please explain what you exactly do with "When the run the application" so it's clear to use if and how you already solved the autoloading.

Comment: Sorry for the typo there, So basically i am getting a Json Array and trying to print it out in a table. That is it. All my code is in one file as it is a very small php SDK. So when i create an http client class i get an error message as shown in my earlier question.

Comment: Well, another solution: if you have your component loaded via composer (I see a composer.json) and in that composer the dependency is specified, load your service with composer in your app. That will fix autoloading issues too.